# Algorithm for assigning 2 list of different objects into connected slots optimally

Tags: scheduling

I would to optimally assign objects into slots. There are 2 lists of 2 different elements that have to be assigned. An element from list 1 must be grouped with an element from list 2 into one slot.

The slots are linked (they have 1 or 2 adjacent slots).

There are some constraints on an exact number of slots that an element from list must be assigned to (each element in list has a specified number of slots that it has to be assigned to, in order to have a solution).

Also, each grouping of elements from one list with elements from the other list gets a group type (the type of the group is given by the element in the first list).

And another constraint is that element from list 2 must participate in certain number of groups with the type(s) that it can give to the group.

The slots have to be filled optimally; they don't have to be all filled, but the better solution is where an element from a list is assigned to as many connected slots as possible (as opposed to participating in many slots that are not connected between themselves)

Example: students (list 1) haves classes (group types) that they have to attend. They must attend certain number of classes (they have a constraint to participate in a certain number of classes of each type; e.g. 3 math classes).

Teachers (list 1) have classes (group types) that they can teach. Teachers (list 1) can teach certain types of classes (group types) and have a certain number of hours (slots with a certain group type) they must fill. E.g. a teacher can teach math and must give 10 math classes (to fulfill its quota)

Of course, all this has to be scheduled, into time slots, so it would be better if both teachers and students are assigned to many connected slots (they attend consecutive classes and dont have big gaps, i.e they attend slots that have only one or none connections with the other slots to which they are assigned to).

I have looked around a bit and found this to be either modeled as graphs and do some "perfect matching" or that this could be treated a "constraint optimization" problem (part of general scheduling).

Suggestions on which algorithm to use/how to model this? Or just tips what to look for/at?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between lists, elements, objects, and slots.  Can you clarify?  Do you really mean there are only 4 elements, 2 in each of the 2 lists?  Is each element an object?  What is meant by "the grouping" and how does that relate to the assignment of objects to slots?  And so on.  I find the problem statement hard to follow.  Perhaps you can provide a mathematical formulation of the task, with a clear list of the inputs and the requirements a valid solution must satisfy.

Comment: @D.W. I did provide an example... the description is just an attempt to abstract the example

Comment: An example is not a substitute for a clear problem statement.  We rely on you to put in the work to figure out how to articulate your problem in a clear way, so answerers can understand what your requirements are and voters can know how to evaluate proposed answers.